# How to catch all of the inner exceptions in the root method?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I'm using a windows service and I would like to catch all of the inner exceptions in my root method.
In one of my inner methods, I'm using a try/catch block like below. When an error occurs, the service doesn't return the error message to my root method. Instead it just throws an error and stops inside my inner method.

How do I return the error message to my root method ?

```
try
{
    loadAdapterProperties(ref strAssemblyName, ref strTypeName, ref statusXML,
       strAssignedTask, ref lastAdapter, ref entityTypeCode, ref adminID);

    if (strAssemblyName == "" || strTypeName == "")
    {
        LogWriter.WriteTimedMessage("No adapters currently available, {0}",
            strAssignedTask);                         
        loopCondition = false;
        break;
    }

    objHandle = Activator.CreateInstance(strAssemblyName, strTypeName);
    objAdapter = (BaseGatesAdapter)objHandle.Unwrap();

    objAdapter.Load(strAssignedTask, statusXML, entityTypeCode, adminID);
    objAdapter.Execute();
    LogWriter.WriteTimedMessage("Executed {0}", strAssemblyName);
    if (lastAdapter == true)
        loopCondition = false;
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    loopCondition = false;                     
    LogWriter.WriteTimedMessage("FAILED to execute {0}",strAssemblyName);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by root method and inner method?  Is the code posted above the root method?  Is the `objAdapter.Execute()` method the inner method?  What does `objAdapter.Execute()` do?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, for your code i understand that the try-catch block was inside a loop (`while`) but if you rethrow the exception your loop will break so simply comment the `throw;` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably mean is that the error message you get when running the app points at the inner method. This means (most likely) that you are not doing try/catch at the root level.

This can be tricky - if you have debugger installed on the machine, the debugger will get notified of this "throw" before your main app is. Depending on debugger configuration it will possibly pause your app. See here on how to turn it off completely:
[Suppress first chance exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948590/suppress-first-chance-exceptions)

Here's explanation on how to sign up to the exception event on the thread level, so you don't have to wrap try/catch on all your methods
[How to catch ALL exceptions/crashes in a .NET app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82483/how-to-catch-all-exceptions-crashes-in-a-net-app)